# Backbone & Underscore: unable to pass model to template for evaluation

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having trouble with passing model data from a Backbone View to a template in Underscore. I want to pass an array into the template so I can evaluate using `_.each`.
My code is below:

**templateSettings**

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Interpolate is  `{{ }}`  and evaluate is `{[ ]}`. Unless my regex is incorrect

**View**

```
el: $('#assasinationBackbone'),
events: {
    'click #newHitJob': 'addNewHitJob'
},
initialize: function() {
},

addNewHitJob: function() {
    var hitMen = new HitManList();
    var template = _.template($('#newHitJobTemplate').html());
    hitMen.fetch({
        success: function() {
            $('#newHitJobForm').html(template(hitMen.toJSON()));
            return hitMen; //CANNOT REMEMBER WHY I PUT THIS HERE (NO SIDE EFFECTS)
        }
    });
});
```

I did not define the template in the view as `template:` , but instead I defined it inside the `addNewHitJob` property.
**1. Is this correct?** I did this because I will have more than one template. The said template is below

**Template (in Jade), I can translate to html if need be**

```
.span4#newHitJobForm
    script#newHitJobTemplate(type="text/template")
        select#names                
        {[ _.each(hitman, function(name) { ]}
        option(value="{{ name._id }}") {{ name.name }}
        {[ }); ]}
```

**2. From what I have seen, My problem is** with passing `hitman` to the template, but I am uncertain. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `evaluate` regex isn't right, you want:

```
evaluate: /\{\[(.+?)\]\}/g
```

Your `evaluate` regex is equivalent to your `interpolate` since `[\S\s]` should match anything just like `.` does.

And when you call an Underscore template, you need to give it an object with the names and values for the template, just handing it an array (`hitMen.toJSON()`) won't do anything useful; you need to give your serialized `hitMen` a name so that the template can refer to them:

```
$('#newHitJobForm').html(template({ hitMen: hitMen.toJSON() }));
```

and then in the template:

```
{[ _.each(hitMen, function(hitMan) { ]}
option(value="{{ hitMan.cat._id }}") {{ hitMan.name }}
{[ }); ]}
```

I had to guess about the `hitMan.cat._id` part.

Comment: Thanks, I must really invest time in my regexpressions, and now that I know how to pass arrays, I'm good to go. It worked!
Sorry about the random example, no people will be hurt in the making of this app ;)